# Use integer array in IN condition PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have integer Array like {10,13,20}

I have to pass this array in IN condition like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE id IN (10,20,30)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE id IN(array_to_string(_array,','))
```

but it's throwing the error `casting operator does not exist: bigint = text`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `_array`? What are you trying to achieve by using `array_to_string`?

Comment: _array is {10,20,30}

Comment: As an array value (from where?)? Or as a literal?

Comment: Array pass to stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=919276c6789743ec499a53797fd67353)

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE id = any(array[10,20,30]::int[]);
```

Comment: I passed array in {10,20,30} this format.

Comment: I have array which in this format : {10,20,30}
Not in this format : array[10,20,30]

Comment: Not diffrence between `array[10,20,30]::int[]` and `{10,20,30}`. You can use both of them https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=56cfe9589a15337dd579690429dcc4e4

Comment: You are right but when pass array in stored procedure its show "{10,20,30}" and throw the error

Comment: @KrunalPandya Please edit your question to show the entire stored procedure definition. Is `_array` really of type `int[]` (or `bigint[]`)?

Comment: Array type is bigint[]

Answer (score 0):

Use `string_to_array` instead of `array_to_string`. Cast the resulting array to `bigint[]` as the type of `id` is `bigint`. Here it is, easy to be parameterized:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM users u
 WHERE id = any(string_to_array('10,20,30',',')::bigint[]);
```

After your clarification that `_array` is an argument or variable of type `bigint[]` then simply:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users u WHERE id = any(_array);
```

Comment: "*the type of `id` is `bigint`.*" - uh, how do you know? The OP didn't share their table definition.

Comment: @Bergi The OP shared the error message 'operator does not exist: bigint = text'

Comment: it's like this 
SELECT count(*) FROM users u
 WHERE id = any(string_to_array({10,20,30},',')::bigint[]);
Its work ?

Comment: No, `string_to_array` expects its first argument to be text, no curly braces are needed. `string_to_array('10,20,30',',')`. Pls. see updated answer.